# message filter for code pipeline message by SNS aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline

I created a SNS subscription and started receiving bunch of emails

I'm interested in receiving only following emails:

All emails with pipeline name and status weather failed or succeeded in message body

```
{"account":"","detailType":"CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change","region":"ap-south-1","source":"aws.codepipeline","time":"","notificationRuleArn":"arn:aws:codestar-notifications:ap-south-1:notificationrule/3a1a2bf7acf27ba4dba4b9bbab0ac14550994ec6","detail":{"pipeline":"demo","execution-id":"2df769bc-37b6-4853-942a-7e2fc1c0b66d","state":"SUCCEEDED","version":5.0},"resources":["arn:aws:codepipeline:ap-south-1"],"additionalAttributes":{}}
```

Tried adding below in subscription filter policy for status :

```
{
  "status": [
    "failed",
    "succeeded"
  ]
}
```

but not even getting notification after this?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to use payload-based message filtering in SNS, as opposed to attribute-based filtering. For that to work, you have to set a subscription attribute named `FilterPolicyScope` to `MessageBody`. Otherwise, this subscriptions attribute defaults to `MessageAttributes`. More info: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/